# Android 2.3 and Blackberry Show Page as Column that Let you Scroll Way to Right and Bottom

Tags: android, html, css, blackberry

Does anyone have a clue what could cause this behavior?  If you view this page on Android 2.3 or Blackberry, you should see the problem.

You can scroll straight past the end of the page to a yellow background that goes on forever.  You can also scroll off the right side of the page to do the same thing.

It works fine on Android 4 and iOS 5.

See site with issue here:

> http://wwwa1nbkclientsitecom.zippysites.com/

p.s.  I asked about this yesterday but with less detail.  And I've made some changes sense then, but those didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the dynamic google map in the footer. It had nothing to do with my page layout or style. Everything I did was fine. Removing the dynamic google map fixed it. SOLUTION: Replace with a STATIC google map. Its kind of bad to be using dynamic map embedded in page for a mobile device anyway.